# How to find the title of the HOTS music while searching?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

When looking for a game in Heroes of the Storm, during the wait time, various music are playing, not totally related to heroes of the storm.

I've tried to look for them and to listen to them individually, but no luck until now.

Do you know where to find theses musics and their title ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're looking for the Queue music, which depending on which period you've been playing might be different. There are also many login themes and map themes but I think those are not what you're looking for.

- [QM Searching BGM used from 2015 to 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWkCs8AGJrU)
- [Brawl Searching BGM used from late 2016 and present-day QM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Rf_xkSkvFo)